# Are CSS variables implemented in any modern browser?

Tags: html, css

I found [this W3C proposal for CSS variables](http://oocss.org/spec/css-variables.html) and was wondering if any modern browsers (i.e. IE7+, Firefox 5+, Chrome) implement them yet?

Comment: idk exactly, but since it's listed as a 'w3c proposal' instead of a standard, it is very unlikely to be implemented in browsers

Comment: Only last year? Wow. If this makes it into the spec, I'll have kids when it does, maybe.

Comment: Not a good SO question since the answer changes every week.

Comment: I'll try better next time.

Comment: CSS variables are now available in Firefox. (see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)

Answer (score 6):

As of this week, WebKit -- which is used by Safari and Chrome -- will be working to implement CSS variables.

http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/120154

Comment: While CSS variables are still considered an experimental technology, Firefox 31 has implemented CSS variables as of today.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference

This is a reference to MDN - they do a pretty good job of listing known browser compatibility.  What is/isn't possible is going to be dependent upon each individual css rule.  The world of web development would be a lot easier if everything followed the specs perfectly; but that is rarely the case.  The @variables rule you referenced isn't listed there, so I'm guessing you're out of luck.  Though there are a lot of mobile browsers coming out as people keep buying newer phones - so you might find somewhere that can use this out in the wild world of mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any browser that uses CSS variables like that. The W3C document you linked was only a proposal, not a standard. Even stanards take a while to get full support in browsers, so I'd imagine widespread implementation is a ways off regardless.

If you want that sort of functionality though, you can look into something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Variables are listed as ["working draft" in CSS3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/), or ["exploring phase"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS3#Variables) which means there is no agreement how best to implement it, or even if it should be.

Browser support will be constantly a moving target so the **answer "No"** is difficult to stake and still be accurate when you read this.  Variables aren't even listed on most [browser comparison charts](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css) (March 2012)

Answer (score 0):

This is not standard in most browser rendering of CSS, it may be part of a working group for the css3 spec though I do not believe I have seen mention of it previously.

It is possible to achieve this kind of effect with the addition of other libraries, the one I am most familiar with is called less CSS which supports some cool stuff like variables and nesting rules but it works by translating that to long form CSS.